# PowerApps collection function results in [object Object]

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a Text input as: 'Topic', 'Date'. and dropdown as:  'EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName' these values `Distinct(employee_table,EmployeeID)` and `Distinct(employee_table,EmployeeName)`

using a generic `Collect` function

```
Collect(List, {Topic: topic.Text, Date: date.Text, EmployeeID: employeeid, EmployeeName: employeename})
```

The Collection table results as: Topic and Date as 'input value'. But, EmployeeID and EmployeeName shows as `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

Since 'EmployeeID' and 'EmployeeName' are dropdowns, you will probably have to use

> EmployeeID.Result

and

> EmployeeName.Result

```
Collect(List, {Topic: topic.Text, Date: date.Text, EmployeeID: EmployeeID.Result, EmployeeName: EmployeeName.Result})
```

Distinct() returns alist of values with the results stored into a "Result" column/property

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues with drop downs going into powerApp. I found the issue, in my case, was due to the fact the drop downs were “multi-select” drop downs and the moment I changed them to single select, it all worked in powerApp using:

ThisItem.’ItemName’.Value